# Are there tools that can make the bottling process easier?

Tags: bottling, equipment

I found this to be the most difficult part during my first attempt at brewing.  All I had was a tube and a racking cane.  Is there anything else to simplify the process and prevent me from ending up with almost a full beer on my kitchen floor?

Comment: I've converted this question to a wiki, as there are many answers. I'll try to reorganize it to make sense that way as well. Great question!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Buy a bottling bucket and a bottling wand, it should cost you less than $15 combined and will save you a ton of pain. Cut a small (2-3") piece of 3/8" beverage tubing and connect the wand directly to the spigot on your bottling bucket, so that it looks like this:

[image]

Notice that I put it over the dishwasher with the door open, the door will catch any spillage. Take sanitized bottle, raise to bottling wand, fill, and set it aside with a cap sitting on the top. Once you've done 6-12, cap a batch. Repeat until your bottling bucket runs empty.

Comment: Bloody brilliant. Why have I not thought of this?!

Comment: I have fully converted to this method and I can say that I am happier with all aspects of my life. I think my hair has started to grow back!

Comment: Wow... that's just... wow. Great idea. Don't need a bottle tree, don't have to worry about spill... dang. That's great. Best tip I've read on bottling so far.

Comment: Dishwashing the bottles is genius, why have I never tried that!

Comment: Do you wash the bottles in the dishwasher too, or just use it as a place to dry them? Could running the dishwasher with sanitizer instead of powder detergent be an option?

Answer (score 3):

I use a spring loaded bottling wand at the end of a tube from the spigot on my bottling bucket.  Sometimes I get leaks.  I'm considering racking directly to a keg next time and doing nothing but kegerators.  Could save a lot of time and washing.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a couple extra tools, but found that most auto-siphons aren't worth the plastic they're made of.
In the end, moving your beer to an ale pale with a spigot (to pour from into bottles), is the best thing you can do with a simple set up.

Answer (score 1):

I put my beer in an ale pail with a spigot. (see my [question about spigots](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/790/spigots-whats-the-consensus))

It's super easy to just open the spigot, fill the bottle, and close the spigot.

I also generally have a pail with sani in it, so I dip, pour, fill, cap, repeat. Makes it much easier.

Comment: Aren't you worried about oxidation splashing the beer into the bottle from the spigot??

Comment: Not really. I tilt the bottles, and the flow isn't that fast. A solution would be to throw 6" of tubing on the spigot so that the beer fills from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to kegs.

---

But seriously, check out the spring loaded [bottling wand](http://morebeer.com/view%5Fproduct/6949/102304/Bottle%5FFiller%5Fwith%5FRemovable%5FSpring%5F3%5F8%5Fin.). Also a racking cane clip to hold it in place.

Answer (score 1):

I too dislike the bottling process the most.  It's easily the most labor intensive.  Aside from what others have said the biggest helps I have found are - friends.  Get one person per station (ie rinse bottle - sanitize bottle - fill bottle - cap it - label it) and it goes much fast.  I know I know - duh - but it just goes that much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I just picked up a counter pressure filler.   Will allow me to keg the beer and carbonate to a specific level without hassling with a bottling bucket or priming sugar.

Answer (score 0):

When using the spring loaded bottling wand I always make sure to pull apart the spring loaded part and soak all the little bits in sanitizing solution.  I have mine connected to the bottling bucket by a 1 inch piece of tubing.

Also, when I keg a batch and want a bottle, I don't wait for it to be carbonated, As soon as fill the keg, I immediately fill several bottles from the sanitized faucet.  I use Munton's carb tabs when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for switching to kegs.  You can use grollers and use a blichmann bottle wand for bringing your brews to others. Kegging is very enjoyable, bottling is hell.  Plus you can control your CO2 volume.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "bottle over dishwasher" technique as well, and it works great!