# Which inkjet-printable labels perform well?

Tags: bottling, labels

I've never bothered to label my beer before, but I think I want to start.  Have you ever used inkjet-printable labels on your brew before?  How did they perform?  Are there any brands of labels that you could either recommend or advise to avoid?

Answer (score 2):

I use Avery 3/4" round labels on the caps and that works great for me. Run a couple of sheets (24 labels per sheet) through the printer for each 5 gallon batch. I can easily identify what is in the bottles, and no clean-up when I re-use the bottles for the next batch.

Comment: This is a great suggestion for getting the desired functionality - being able to identify your beer.  It would never be mistaken for a case of form-over-function, though.  :D

Answer (score 1):

I used some Avery labels one time. I don't recall which number. They work great, except they don't come off. The adhesive used is pretty solid. When you soak a bottle in water, the top portion with the ink sort of crumbles, but the adhesive sticks. It's not ideal for reuse.

Lately, when I've been sharing brews, I put a vinyl sticker on the bottle. These don't come off easily at all, but they also don't fall apart when you're cleaning them.

I'm sure there's a better option, like what the "good" breweries in [this list](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/892/) use, but I don't know what they are.