# Secondary fermentaton objectives

Tags: bottling

I recently racked to a secondary, an amber ale of grain and extract of my own recipe after fermentation seemed complete. Am I doing my ale a favor by doing this and will it increase clarity and flavor? The taste and aroma are exactly what I'm looking for. I plan to bottle and condition in 5 days.

Comment: welcome to HB exchange! :D

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've already racked, you probably don't want to hear this, but the common wisdom is to not rack to secondary at all. See [If/When to rack to secondary](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/88/if-when-to-move-to-secondary-fermentation).

If you performend a "clean" rack without introducing any oxygen or contaminants, then the beer will be fine with the added bonus of racking to the bottling bucket will be even easier since you have next to no trub to avoid. But I can't say that it will benefit your bear in any way.

Some commercial breweries transfer the beer to bright tanks - large shallow tanks that make it easier for the beer to clear. Your secondary can function as a bright tank, but you need to leave it for at least a couple of weeks to get any noticable clarification.

If you're only leaving it in secondary for 5 days then you don't need to do it - next time just bottle instead and save yourself a racking.

Comment: What's his bear got to do with it?

Comment: Bears hate sediment in their bottles. And angry bears find homebrewers delicious, as we are already pre-marinated with booze. So it's pretty important to keep the bears happy.