# How likely to get off flavors from American Ale transferring to secondary?

Tags: secondary-fermentation

I transferred my American Ale from primary to secondary after 10/11 days. I guess fermentation is pretty much complete. I might be going away for 3 weeks and so I didnt want the beer sitting in the primary for that long since I wont have time for bottling. After reading this: [If/When to move to secondary fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/88/if-when-to-move-to-secondary-fermentation)

I am wondering how likely it is that I have gotten some off flavors from oxidation? The second fermenter 30 liters with 23/24 liters of beer and so there is a good amount of oxygen inside but I was careful not to splash the beer during transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you practiced good siphoning technique and minimized splashing of the beer I think you should be just fine. I personally rack most of my beers to secondary (This isn't actually considered "Best Practice" anymore) because I dnjoy really clear beer.

I have never experienced the effects of oxidization but am very careful to let the fluid drain along the side of my container until the level is high enough I can submerge the end of my siphon.

Make sure your secondary container has as little head space as possible to help minimize oxidization as well.

The post you references has this quote

> Autolysis (the process by which yeast break down and die) isn't really a problem for homebrewers, unless you're keeping your beer on the yeast cake for many months to years

Keeping your beer in primary for over 3 weeks is really pushing it in my opinion. Sure some people may have success but its not a good practice. It is definitely possible for a beer which has sat on primary for over 3 weeks to see some effect of autolysis. I would rather rack my beer then risk autolysis.

Comment: One other thing - store it cold. If there is any oxygen in there, each 18F/10C drop reduces the oxidization rate 3-fold. And of course, this will help the beer clear also.

Comment: I agree with everything in the answer except the risk of autolysis at 3 weeks.

Comment: To clarify, I typically leave all my beers in primary for 3 weeks. It probably could be better stated. but anything approaching 4 weeks I feel isn't worth the risk. Would you feel differently on that?

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't.  I have personally gone 2 months without a problem and know others who have gone far longer.  Is it a great idea?  Likely not.  Is it a problem?  Not in my experience.

Comment: I wonder if the quality of yeast & malt is such that problems with long primaries have disappeared, or if it was some other factor causing autolysis all along.

Comment: As far as my research has been able to discover, much of the past warning about autolysis is based on commercial brewing, not homebrewing.  Commercial brewers have large amount of beer, and hence weight, sitting in tall narrow fermenters.  The pressure from all the beer can cause sells to burst and autolyse.  Homebrewers OTOH use shorter, wider fermenters with much less beer and consequently weight on the yeast.  Once again we have a situation where what applies to commercial breweries does not necessarily apply to homebrewers.

Comment: I have had autolysis after 3 weeks, and not just once but twice. Friends have also had the same problem.

Comment: I would have to say that you're the exception.

Comment: Autolysis even as described by Palmer is vague and not substantiated by any sort of evidence. Here is a reference saying that there is NO risk of autolysis at the homebrew scale in the less than a month (http://www.themadfermentationist.com/2012/02/11-mistakes-every-new-homebrewer-makes.html), and I would extend that further. Autolysis is yeast cells exploding which requires some pretty harsh conditions, which are not going to occur in a beer. Heat, extreme pHs, extreme alcohol content etc would be required.