# Post-Secondary Fermentation

Tags: beer, cider, secondary-fermentation

I've heard mentions of people using tertiary, quaternary, quinary, etc fermentations.  Does this really provide any significant benefit beyond secondary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this same answer applies here:

[What's the point of secondary fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/68/whats-the-point-of-secondary-fermentation)

The purpose of n-ary isn't more fermentation, but aging, clarifying, etc.

So for me, no it doesn't provide any additional benefit. The only time I use a secondary vessel is for fruit additions or extended aging. I've never found a need for a third vessel.

Comment: This. I've heard of some people who are overly anal about clarity racking three or four times, but it's honestly not necessary and just increases the risk of oxidation or, to a lesser extent, infection.

Comment: Sometimes the purpose of n-ary fermentation is more fermentation. You can work with higher "effective" O.G. by adding additional sugars ( and possibly more yeast ). I make a quad that I add boiled molasses to after primary fermentation; and I add a type of indian date sugar boiled in water and additional yeast before tertiary fermentation. For extremely high gravity beers I don't think this is unreasonable.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard of having a tertiary phase if you add fruit (etc.) to the beer during the secondary, to help precipitate out the fruit particles before bottling.

Answer (score 2):

I can't get a pumpkin ale clean with only a secondary for the life of me.  Next batch I plan on using a tertiary.  Just be careful with splashing, I've been careless and oxidized the hell out of an otherwise good beer before.